# Файловый менеджер на vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js

У меня есть задание написать файловый менеджер на vue.js - frontend и на php - backend.
Я примерно понимаю, что на php нужно написать API, которая будет работать с БД и генерировать json файл, а затем скармливать его vue, но не смог в интернете найти ничего полезного как это конкретно можно реализовать и связать backend и frontend. Если есть какие либо годные примеры или советы буду очень благодарен.(сборщик webpack)

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю? Вам с БД работать или с ФС? У вас же задание - файловый менеджер.

Comment: С бд мне нужно получать список находящихся там файлов и возможность работать с ними (удалять, загружать, скачивать). На vue просто представление того, что там есть. Если я не прав, то можете объяснить как правильно?

Comment: Да при чем тут "прав, не прав"? Просто зачем вам в БД хранить данные о ФС,

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто:
Делаем запрос к серверу за списком файлов, пихаем полученное в свойство  `data` и радуемся.
При необходимости просто редактируем свойство `data`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('dir-view', {
  props: ['dir'],
  template: `
  <div class="dir">
    <label>
      {{ dir.name }}
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <div class='content'>
        <div class='children' v-for="child in dir.children">
          <dir-view v-if="child.children.length" :dir="child"></dir-view>
          <span v-else>{{ child.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        name: "L4D2.exe",
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: "System",
        children: [
          {
            name: "kernel32.dll",
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "Porn",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Hot.mkv",
                children: []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Calc.exe",
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Referats",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Quantum mechanics.pdf",
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.content, input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}
.content {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .content {
  display: block;
}
label:before {
  content: '> ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class='item' v-for="item in items">
    <dir-view v-if="item.children.length" :dir="item"></dir-view>
    <span v-else>{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На днях делал аналогичную работу на React. Рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, а взять за основу API от Яндекса [документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/api/reference/capacity-docpage/)